# Change event is not called when checked value changed using ref

Tags: checkbox, vue.js, reference

I was trying to create a `select all` feature. Following is my component,

```js
(function(){
 var template = ' <table>\
      <tr>\
       <td rowspan=2><input type="checkbox" @change="allSelectChanged"/>All</td>\
      </tr>\
      <tr v-for="i in rows">\
       <td  ><input type="checkbox" ref="select" @change="changedSelection(i,$event)" />Selection {{i}}</td>\
      </tr>\
     </table>';
 var component = { 
  template : template,
  data:function(){
   return {
    rows:5
   }
  },
  methods:{
   allSelectChanged:function(e){
    _.each(this.$refs.select,function(s){
     s.checked = e.target.checked;
    });
   },
   changedSelection:function(i,e){
    console.log("Selection changed",i,e.target.checked);
   }
  }
 }
    Vue.component('sample', component);
})();

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
  },
  methods:{ 
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script> 
<script src="https://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script> 

</style> 
<div id="app">  
 <sample />
</div>
```

When I checked/unchecked any checbox `changedSelection` function is called. But when I checked/unchecked `all` checkbox, check boxes are getting selected but respective `changedSelection` function is not getting called.

Why `changedSelection` is not called when the change is made through ref??

Answer (score 1):

Instead set new element in vue data and use bind with `v-model="selection"`

```js
new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data:{
    rows:[{id:1,sel:false},{id:2,sel:false},{id:3,sel:false},{id:4,sel:false},{id:5,sel:false}],
    selection:false,
    selAll:false
  },
  methods:{
    changedSelection:function(i){
        console.log(i.id +" is "+ (i.sel?' checked ': 'unchecked') );
    },
    changedAllSelection:function(){
        for(let i in this.rows){
          this.rows[i].sel = this.selAll;
          console.log(this.rows[i].id +" is "+ (this.rows[i].sel?' checked ': 'unchecked') );
        }
        console.log("Select All : " + this.selAll);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<div>
<input type="checkbox" ref="select" v-model="selAll" @change="changedAllSelection" />Selection All : {{(selAll?' checked ': 'unchecked')}}
<div v-for="i in rows">
<input type="checkbox" ref="select" v-model="i.sel" @change="changedSelection(i)" />Selection {{i.id}} : {{(i.sel?' checked ': 'unchecked')}}
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you @C2486. the selection works fine. The actual issue is when I use a single checkbox to perform check/uncheck operation,  `changedSelection` is not triggering.

Comment: @Kajal : Please update your question with snippet/live demo as I did. which is not working for you ?

Comment: Edited code with snippet. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: The code you provided is working, what is expected  ?

Comment: When you click the first checkbox named `All`. It selects all the check boxes, But respective `change` event (`changedSelection`) is not getting triggered.

Comment: I have changed my answer for `select All`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179626/discussion-between-kajal-and-c2486).